# CSS working for chrome but not for firefox

Tags: css

My CSS code below is working fine in Chrome, but isn't working in Firefox.  I think it might just be a syntactical difference but I can't figure out what is going on.  Are there any mistakes in my CSS code below?

```
#framed_source {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 97%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

#grey_cover {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #3F3F3F;
    /* Transparency is applied through the transparent class */
}

#popup_window {
    background: #D0E9F3;
    visibility: visible;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
}

.with_frame {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
}

#popup_window_content {
    overflow: auto;
    color: #1F313E;
    font-family: Calibri;
    max-height: 200px;
}

.transparent {
        /* Required for IE 5, 6, 7 */
        /* ...or something to trigger hasLayout, like zoom: 1; */
        width: 100%; 

        /* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */
        /* ...but not required as filter works too */
        /* should come BEFORE filter */
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

        /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
        /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);

        /* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
        -moz-opacity:0.5;

        /* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

        /* Modern!
        /* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
        /* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
        opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Basically I have a popup window that is displaying on top of an iframe.  In Chrome it does this correctly, in FF it displays the popup beneath the iframe.  Any ideas?  I think it has to do with absolute / relative positioning.

[Picture of Firefox -- Incorrect CSS](http://i1197.photobucket.com/albums/aa428/doodledude111/firefox--incorrectCSS.jpg)
[Picture of Chrome -- Correct CSS](http://i1197.photobucket.com/albums/aa428/doodledude111/chrome--correctCSS.jpg)

I also created a [JSFiddle for this CSS with the corresponding HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/CH6ny/5/).  I am trying to get the blue box appearing below the frame to appear centered in front of the frame.

Comment: Could it be a zIndex issue?  I don't see you specifying it at any point...

Comment: I prefer to answer questions where i can check out the problem myself or where its easy to jsfiddle the code. Also i dont know what the problem could be right off the bat.

Comment: Side-note:  In some places you're using `background:` and in other places you're using `background-color:`.  I'd stick with the latter.

Comment: I would only use `background-color` with emails but otherwise there is no reason to use it. Plus `background` is shorter. @Kvass i have a bit of a dyslexia plus i dont quite understand your id's and classes, would you mind pointing out which one is the element that gives you trouble?

Comment: I will post a picture of the correct appearance in chrome and the incorrect one in firefox in a moment -- that should make the css that's causing the issue more apparent.

Comment: @Jagan that post is PHP related

Comment: I think that was just a shameless promotion. At least thats the his profile indicates.

Comment: sorry i miss pasted the copied link.. thanks for notifying

Comment: no prob -- so does anyone have any ideas based on the pics?  for the most part all the "popup" related ids correspond to the popup window that you see, framed_source corresponds to the website in the background.

Comment: @Kvass I really couldnt connect the dots with the code, but i hope this little example helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/SNpR8/ ( as this currently is, it should work in all the major browsers and ie6+ )

Comment: Convenient website Lollero, thank you I will play around with it and see if it does the trick.

Comment: I created a JSfiddle with an example HTML that I would want to use this CSS with.  Hopefully that will make it more convenient (see my edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in the end this is what was wrong.

1. Having `<iframe>` above the `popup` in the html structure somehow messed up with the `positioning` of the `popup`.
2. Since `html` and `body` were just hanging out there, they didnt stretch all the way to the bottom and restricted iframe from going further as its height was set with percentage.. ( This is something i do remember fixing at some point.. but it was already past midnight when i was checking into it, so who knows where that disappeared :D )

http://fiddle.jshell.net/CH6ny/6/

Comment: unfortunately though it appears to work in JSFiddle this didn't solve the problem in FireFox -- the iframe is still being scrunched at the top, while it is supposed to span the full length of the page this is a picture of how it appears: http://i1197.photobucket.com/albums/aa428/doodledude111/firefox--incorrectCSS.jpg

Comment: Compare that picture with the desired display: http://i1197.photobucket.com/albums/aa428/doodledude111/chrome--correctCSS.jpg

Comment: What the heck.. i thought i made it in firefox.. I gotta check it out tomorrow.

Comment: I really appreciate your help btw

Comment: the issue resolved itself in ff5 for some reason, but i upvoted for the time u took to help me out anyway

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know why, but when I upgraded to Firefox 5 the issue resolved itself.  Thank you everyone for all your time anyway!

Answer (score 0):

To get something to appear on top of another, you will need to set the z-index values and I think also set the position.

For the element that you want to be on top, set the z-index value like this:

```
#idOfTopElement {
    z-index: 1;
}
#idOfNextElement {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

You might need to add `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` to one or both of those depending on what position you are using, but I can't remember for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not completely against a javascript/jQuery solution, here is an option that might work. I chose to do the top and left adjustments onload, but it would make more sense to do it when you call the creation of the popup_window:

http://jsfiddle.net/CH6ny/4/

It worked in Chrome, FF, IE, and IE quirks mode.